# Reading the property of my object from the user input

Tags: c#, methods, properties, readline

I am a beginner at coding and English is not my native language.

Would you look at this code and my comments, please?

For reasons of space, I left out the code from my class `Player`.

I want to know what I have to write instead of `Alex.damage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

```
namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Player
    {
        private int _health = 100;

        public int health
        {
            get
            {
                return _health;
            }
        }

        public void damage (int _dmg)
        {
            _health -= _dmg;
        }
    }
}

class Programm
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         Player Alex = new Player();
         Console.WriteLine("Wie viel Damage soll ausgeteilt werden?"); // "How much 
        //damage should be done"
        Alex.damage = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // there is the error 
        //"'damage' is a methodgroup, therfore an assigment is not possible"
        Console.WriteLine(Alex.health);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the code for class `Player`.

Comment: Well, my guess is that it should be `Alex.damage(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));` and inside of function `damage` you reduce player's health

Comment: Thanks Fabjan, it worked. So obvious^^

Answer (score 1):

The member `damage` is a method so you cannot assign an integer to it.

What you need to do instead is **call the method** and pass the value as a parameter. I would recommend collecting the value in a variable first. It makes it easier to read and debug:

```
var value = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Alex.damage(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate what needs to be acheived.if your tring to send value to damage method you can call the method by sending the parameter

```
     var damagefromuser=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     Alex.damage(damagefromuser);
```

if you are trying  to read from the method you can return the value you want from the method

```
          public int damage (int _dmg)
        {

              return _dmg;
        }
```